# How to order images in a post in Wordpress 3.3?

Tags: images, media-library, uploads, wordpress-version

In wordpress 3.2 when uploading images to a post, I would get a Gallery that is linked to the post. That is, I could see in the media uploader of the post a tab that contains only the images of this post, and there would be a place to mark the order of the images I wanted for the post.

In wordpress 3.3 I can only see the media library of all the images I have ever uploaded, and I cannot order them in any way.

Is there a way to order the images related to a post?
Have I somehow managed to upload the images incorrectly so that they are not attached to a post?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, media management didn't change from WP 3.2 to 3.3 (except for replacing the uploader itself with PLuploader). It has *always* been possible to upload images directly to the media manager (by uploading via Dashboard -> Media Library ), in which case such uploaded images would not be attached to any particular post.

To test that things are working properly, go to the edit post screen for a post that you know already has attached images, and verify that the media manager still displays the menu order field for the image gallery. Then, create a new post, upload some images, and again verify that the media manager still displays the menu order field.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what I did different the last time I tried. You are correct, this still works the same.